# SurfaceHolder CallBack not triggering

Tags: android, callback, surfaceview

The following class will take a photo with the front facing camera and store it in the android gallery:

```
  public class TakePicture extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
// a variable to store a reference to the Image View at the main.xml file
  // private ImageView iv_image;
 // a variable to store a reference to the Surface View at the main.xml file
private SurfaceView sv;

// a bitmap to display the captured image
private Bitmap bmp;
FileOutputStream fo;

// Camera variables
// a surface holder
private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
// a variable to control the camera
private Camera mCamera;
// the camera parameters
private Camera.Parameters parameters;
private String FLASH_MODE;
private boolean isFrontCamRequest = false;
private Camera.Size pictureSize;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.background);

    // check if this device has a camera

        // get the Image View at the main.xml file
        // iv_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        // get the Surface View at the main.xml file
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        FLASH_MODE = "FLASH_MODE_OFF";
        boolean front_cam_req = true;
        isFrontCamRequest = front_cam_req;

        sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        // Get a surface
        sHolder = sv.getHolder();

        // add the callback interface methods defined below as the Surface
        // View
        // callbacks
        sHolder.addCallback(this);

        // tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly
        // replaced
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
            sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);



}

/** Check if this device has a camera */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

/** Check if this device has front camera */
private boolean checkFrontCamera(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
        // this device has front camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no front camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // get camera parameters
    if (mCamera != null) {
        parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        if (FLASH_MODE == null || FLASH_MODE.isEmpty()) {
            FLASH_MODE = "auto";
        }
        parameters.setFlashMode(FLASH_MODE);
        pictureSize = getBiggesttPictureSize(parameters);
        if (pictureSize != null)
            parameters
                    .setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);
        // set camera parameters
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        mCamera.startPreview();

        // sets what code should be executed after the picture is taken
        Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                // decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap
                Log.d("ImageTakin", "Done");

                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                if (bmp != null)
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);


                //FOR GALLERY STORAGE ---- TEST
                File androidVidGalleryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                File imagesFolder = new File(androidVidGalleryPath+"/Guardian");
                if (!imagesFolder.exists())
                    imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----


                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                Integer guardianCount = pref.getInt("guardianCountimg",0);

                File image = new File(androidVidGalleryPath+"/Guardian/img_"+String.valueOf(guardianCount)+".jpg");

                editor.putInt("guardianCountimg",guardianCount+1).commit();


                // write the bytes in file
                try {
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(image);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
                try {
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }

                // remember close de FileOutput
                try {
                    fo.close();
                    //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"
                      //      + Environment
                        //    .getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(image)));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
                if (mCamera != null) {
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    // release the camera
                    mCamera.release();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Invalid login\n\nRegistered owner will be notified!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                if (bmp != null) {
                    bmp.recycle();
                    bmp = null;
                    System.gc();
                }
                TakePicture.this.finish();

            }
        };

        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw the preview.
    if (isFrontCamRequest) {

        // set flash 0ff
        FLASH_MODE = "off";
        // only for gingerbread and newer versions
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            mCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

            } catch (IOException exception) {
                mCamera = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "API dosen't support front camera",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TakePicture.this.finish();
            }
        } else {
            if (checkFrontCamera(getApplicationContext())) {
                mCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    mCamera = null;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "API dosen't support front camera",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    TakePicture.this.finish();
                }
            }/*
         * else { // API dosen't support front camera or no front camera
         * Log.d("Camera",
         * "API dosen't support front camera or no front camera");
         * Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
         * "API dosen't support front camera or no front camera",
         * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         *
         * finish(); }
         */

        }
    } else {
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // stop the preview
/*
 * mCamera.stopPreview(); // release the camera mCamera.release();
 */
    // unbind the camera from this object
    mCamera = null;
}

private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera",
                        "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Front Camera failed to open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
    return cam;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
    // You can also include some extra data.
    intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

    super.onDestroy();
}

private Camera.Size getBiggesttPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result = null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
        if (result == null) {
            result = size;
        } else {
            int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
            int newArea = size.width * size.height;

            if (newArea > resultArea) {
                result = size;
            }
        }
    }

    return (result);
}

}
```

The issue is that i would like to do this without having to start a new activity using :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TakePicture.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Instead i've added this activity's code in the on create section to a method called takePic() and moved the required methods, shown below :

```
  public void takePic(){

    FLASH_MODE = "FLASH_MODE_OFF";
    boolean front_cam_req = true;
    isFrontCamRequest = front_cam_req;
    sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    sHolder = sv.getHolder();
    sHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
            // to draw the preview.
            if (isFrontCamRequest) {

                // set flash 0ff
                FLASH_MODE = "off";
                // only for gingerbread and newer versions
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                    mCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
                    try {
                        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

                    } catch (IOException exception) {
                        mCamera = null;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "API dosen't support front camera",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //TakePicture.this.finish();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (checkFrontCamera(getApplicationContext())) {
                        mCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
                        try {
                            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

                        } catch (IOException exception) {
                            mCamera = null;
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "API dosen't support front camera",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //TakePicture.this.finish();
                        }
                    }/*
         * else { // API dosen't support front camera or no front camera
         * Log.d("Camera",
         * "API dosen't support front camera or no front camera");
         * Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
         * "API dosen't support front camera or no front camera",
         * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         *
         * finish(); }
         */

                }
            } else {
                mCamera = getCameraInstance();
                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    mCamera = null;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            // get camera parameters
            if (mCamera != null) {
                parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                if (FLASH_MODE == null || FLASH_MODE.isEmpty()) {
                    FLASH_MODE = "auto";
                }
                parameters.setFlashMode(FLASH_MODE);
                pictureSize = getBiggesttPictureSize(parameters);
                if (pictureSize != null)
                    parameters
                            .setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);
                // set camera parameters
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

                mCamera.startPreview();

                // sets what code should be executed after the picture is taken
                Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        // decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap
                        Log.d("ImageTakin", "Done");

                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        if (bmp != null)
                            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);


                        //FOR GALLERY STORAGE ---- TEST
                        File androidVidGalleryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                        File imagesFolder = new File(androidVidGalleryPath+"/Guardian");
                        if (!imagesFolder.exists())
                            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----

                        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                        Integer guardianCount = pref.getInt("guardianCountimg",0);

                        File image = new File(androidVidGalleryPath+"/Guardian/img_"+String.valueOf(guardianCount)+".jpg");

                        editor.putInt("guardianCountimg",guardianCount+1).commit();


                        // write the bytes in file
                        try {
                            fo = new FileOutputStream(image);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                        try {
                            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }

                        // remember close de FileOutput
                        try {
                            fo.close();
                            //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"
                            //      + Environment
                            //    .getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(image)));

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                        if (mCamera != null) {
                            mCamera.stopPreview();
                            // release the camera
                            mCamera.release();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Invalid login\n\nRegistered owner will be notified!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        if (bmp != null) {
                            bmp.recycle();
                            bmp = null;
                            System.gc();
                        }
                        //TakePicture.this.finish();



                    }
                };

                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            mCamera = null;
        }
    });

    // tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly
    // replaced
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
        sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

}

/** Check if this device has a camera */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

/** Check if this device has front camera */
private boolean checkFrontCamera(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
        // this device has front camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no front camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}



private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera",
                        "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Front Camera failed to open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
    return cam;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
    // You can also include some extra data.
    intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

    super.onDestroy();
}

private Camera.Size getBiggesttPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result = null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
        if (result == null) {
            result = size;
        } else {
            int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
            int newArea = size.width * size.height;

            if (newArea > resultArea) {
                result = size;
            }
        }
    }

    return (result);
}
```

When using the takePic() method, the picture is not taken until i go back to the homescreen and reopen the app.

**Why is the picture not taken as soon as i call takePic()?**

Answer (score 1):

The SurfaceView's Surface is created asynchronously, some time after `onCreate()` finishes.  Your `takePic()` method is establishing the callbacks, but if it does so after the Surface has already been created, then the callbacks won't be invoked until the next time the Surface is created (such as when rotating the device).

Tying the capture to the preview Surface creation callbacks seems a bit backward, especially given the [quirky nature](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity) of SurfaceView.